# Multiple loop conditions for a set of checkbox choices

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, checkbox

Using CodeIgniter, I am creating an admin area where I am able to create footnotes for any given product line.

**HTML**

```
<p>Choose Product Line</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="productline[]" value="1" />Product One</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="productline[]" value="2" />Product Two</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="productline[]" value="3" />Product Three</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="productline[]" value="4" />Product Four</label>
```

**PHP**

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $this->input->post( 'product[]' ) ); $i++ )
{
    $line__id = $this->input->post( 'product' )[$i];

    $footnote_data = array(
        'line__id' => $line__id,
        'code' => $this->input->post( 'footnotecode' ),
        'text' => $this->input->post( 'footnotetext' ),
        'status' => $this->input->post( 'status' ),
        'createdon' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
    );

    error_log( print_r( $footnote_data, true ) );
}
```

Which will output something like this:

**LOG:**

```
Array
(
    [line__id] => 1
    [code] => ABC123
    [text] => Hello World
    [status] => 1
    [createdon] => 2014-12-31 22:28:59
)

Array
(
    [line__id] => 2
    [code] => ABC123
    [text] => Hello World
    [status] => 1
    [createdon] => 2014-12-31 22:28:59
)
....
```

All is fine, I'm looping through each product line that was selected.

As you can see in the `$footnote_data` array, I have several other fields. They are simple text input fields, and are 1:1 with the current iteration of the loop `$i`.

I also have 2 other checkbox choices. You have to choose the product line (above) then enter the code and actual footnote text. Then, you have to choose what *type* of footnote this is.

**HTML**

```
<p>Footnote Type</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="footnotetype[]" value="awesome" />Awesome</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="footnotetype[]" value="cool" />Cool</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="footnotetype[]" value="average" />Average</label>
```

I can choose as many footnote types that I want for the current footnote I am creating.
I'm just not sure the best way to dive into the second series of checkboxes (the type).

I have tried a nested loop within the main productline loop, but that didn't get the result(s) I was looking for. If I log the result I am looking for, this is what it would look like:

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [line__id] => 2
    [type] => Awesome
    [code] => ABC123
    [text] => Hello World
    [status] => 1
    [createdon] => 2014-12-31 22:28:59
)

Array
(
    [line__id] => 2
    [type] => Cool
    [code] => ABC123
    [text] => Hello World
    [status] => 1
    [createdon] => 2014-12-31 22:28:59
)

Array
(
    [line__id] => 3
    [type] => Average
    [code] => ABC123
    [text] => Hello World
    [status] => 1
    [createdon] => 2014-12-31 22:28:59
)

....
```

See how the same product line can have multiple footnote types? The actual record would/could be exactly the same for each product line selected. Only the type could be different.

Another thought I had - once the initial loop is done - and I have a footnote ID for the newly created footnote, do I turn right around and update the db for each footnote type?
I'm talking myself in circles...

My DB structure looks like this:

**DATABASE**

```
footnote_id
type_id  // this is the question
text
code
status
createdon
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test the code, so maybe there is an error somewhere :

```
$products_data = array();
foreach ($this->input->post('product') ) as $product_id)
{
    $footnote_data = array(
        'line__id' => $product_id,
        'code' => $this->input->post( 'footnotecode' ),
        'text' => $this->input->post( 'footnotetext' ),
        'status' => $this->input->post( 'status' ),
        'createdon' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
    );

    foreach($this->input->post('footnotetype') as $type){
       $footnote_data['type'] = $type;
       array_push($products_data, $footnote_data);
    }

    // error_log( print_r( $footnote_data, true ) );
}
var_dump($products_data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the nudge I needed to get rolling.

Comment: Glad that I could help ^^